# How to turn columns into rows depending on cell conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

Below is an example of my data:

| Omschrijving | AMM | AM | FG | G | K-MOTRED | MINI | BPM-RVM-MOTRED | STM-RMI-MOTRED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 x magneetplug | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| 2 x afwaterings gat zijde 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 x magneetplug |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |
| 3 x afwateringskanaal zijde 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 x waterafvoer zijde B |  |  |  |  | 2 |  |  |  |
| 4 x afwateringsgat A-zijde |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 x afwateringskanaal A-zijde |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Draairichtingspijl links | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

If there is a number in the cell I want it to combine the column header with the data from the first row. See the table below:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMM | 1 x magneetplug | 1 |
| AM | 2 x magneetplug | 1 |
| FG | 3 x magneetplug | 1 |
| G | 4 x magneetplug | 1 |
| K-MOTRED | 5 x magneetplug | 1 |
| BPM-RVM-MOTRED | 6 x magneetplug | 1 |
| BPM-RVM-MOTRED | 2 x magneetplug | 1 |
| K-MOTRED | 3 x waterafvoer zijde B | 2 |
| AMM | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| AM | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| FG | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| G | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| K-MOTRED | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| MINI | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| BPM-RVM-MOTRED | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| STMI-RMI-MOTRED | Draairichtingspijl links | 2 |
| AMM | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| AM | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| FG | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| G | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| K-MOTRED | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| MINI | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| BPM-RVM-MOTRED | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |
| STMI-RMI-MOTRED | Flens en pasvlak meegespoten | 2 |

I am not that experienced with Excel and have no clue how to tackle this problem.

Comment: What is the logic to get just one row in the output for: `1 x magneetplug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> will be the easiest approach. To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the **Power Query** window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Omschrijving"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Omschrijving", "Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Attribute", "Some Header"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result. (Refer .Gif below)

---

[image]

---

See the .Gif --> I have used a shortcut to open the <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window --> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to select the data) --> then hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>PT</kbd> and press ok.

[image]

---

An alternative approach, using **New MS365 Excel Functions** viz. <kbd>TAKE( )</kbd>, <kbd>DROP( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>, <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd>, <kbd>SEQUENCE( )</kbd>, <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A1:I10,
     b,TAKE(DROP(a,1),,1),
     c,DROP(TAKE(a,1),,1),
     d,DROP(a,1,1),
     e,TOCOL(IFNA(b,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d)))),
     f,TOCOL(IFNA(c,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)))),
     g,TOCOL(d),
     h,HSTACK(f,e,g),
     FILTER(h,INDEX(h,,3)<>0))
```

---

Edit : 7/21/2023

A more simple & sleek approach using <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A12</kbd>

```
=HSTACK(
        TOCOL(IF(B2:I10="",NA(),B1:I1),3),
        TOCOL(IF(B2:I10="",NA(),A2:A10),3),
        TOCOL(B2:I10,1)
        )
```

---

Comment: I was about to post the solution using Excel formula, but I see you already did it at the end. Great solution!

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, but `Power Query` is the easiest way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: True, but since I use Excel Web mainly, I prefer to have a solution that works for desktop and web. For simple transformations, like this one I tend to have a solution that would work in both environments. Good to know the trick you use to get the column repetitions via `IFNA`. I consider using `IF` is more intuitive, for example: `TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d)),b))`, but yours is a good alternative too.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir. Great Stuff.